# SQL Server: nop updates gradually slower, why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, latency, fragmentation

Every minute, this program reads a set of records from um DB e replicates them in another DB. 99% of the time, it consists of a No Operation because the data did not change.

The problem is that individual overwrites were becoming slower. With 2500 records, it became noticeable.

If the data does not change, why is SQL gradually becoming slower?

More details: back then, I used GUID as Primary Keys (poor me, I know). But as far as I understand, fragmentation is caused only if there are new inserts or the updates change the size of the data, in both cases, causing page splits. My theory is that these nop updates is fragmenting something (not easily spotable) and causing the increase in latency. Perhaps SQL server implements this update as a delete/insert transaction?

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a no-op, even if the data did not actually change. an After update trigger, for example, will fire on every update statement, even if no data was changed in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Fragmentation is not the only reason why the random GUIDs slow performance.  More IO is needed because rows are distributed evenly throughout the table.  This often results in performance that gradually degrades as the database size increases, especially with traditional spinning media.  Remember that data must first be read into memory even if no data are updated.  The likelihood of the page with a needed row already being in memory is reduced with purely random key requests.

If you must use GUIDs, consider a sequential value assigned with NEWSEQUENTIALID or UuidCreateSequential and some byte swapping.  See my [Improving Uniqueidentifier Performance](http://www.dbdelta.com/improving-uniqueidentifier-performance/) post for a code example and additional details of this common performance problem.

Comment: "As the database size increases...", sure as inserts take place. I measured latency increase  in total absence of new data.